# HTML Navbar not clickable because of overlay

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I am trying to create a dashboard page. I am personally not a fan of CSS and I can never find my way in the code, but this is what I designed:
[image]

Currently, I have this code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600,700&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    --navbar-height: 70px;
    --color-primary: #547430;
    --text-color-on-primary: white;
    --base-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) ), url(src/assets/images/background2.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color:#464646;
    height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}


html, body { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif; }


@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    * {
        --default-desktop-width: 100%;
    }
}

.menu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #3D5021;
    z-index: -1;
}

nav {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.menuButtonIcon {
    color: #FFFFFF60;
}

.menuButtonIcon .fas {
    font-size: 25px;
}

nav ul li:hover i {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}






.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100vw - 100px);
    right: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.content {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <div class="selector"></div>
            <li>
                <label for="btnDashboard" class="menuButtonIcon selected"><i
                    class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="btnDashboard" checked>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="btnList" class="menuButtonIcon"><i class="fas fa-list-ul"></i></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="btnList">
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="btnHeatMap" class="menuButtonIcon"><i class="fas fa-map"></i></label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="btnHeatMap">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Here comes the dashboard content
    </div>

</div>
```

The snippet is not responsive yet, but first I have 2 other problems. When I hover on an item in the menu, the color doesn't change, while I have:

```
nav ul li:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I think its because the container is the overlay, so you can't reach for the navbar, but I don't know how to fix it, because the container need to be placed on top, for the rounded corners. Also I want a white selector box in the navbar, that shifts up and down, depending on the selected item. When an item is selected the color should be turning orange, but I can't figure out how to use the selector in that way.

Can someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: I want the icon color to change, but when I do that, nothing changes when I hover. I tried you last: `nav ul li:hover .fas {...}`

Comment: What exactly is it you want to change color? You've set it up so the list element change color, but if you want it's background to change color you need to change it to set it to background: #FFFFFF;

If it's the icon you want you need to select the icon nav ul li:hover .fas {...}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the icon color to change you need to select the icon on the li:hover.

Either

```
nav ul li:hover i {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or

```
nav ul li:hover .fas {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Or even

```
nav ul li:hover i.fas {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TokerX/ny53m9fa/1/
Also updated the width of the container to +4% instead of -4%, so that it doesn't overlap the menu, although you might want to consider a fixed width for your menu and subtract that from the container width, or add it as a left margin to your container.

Comment: Sorry my bad... The problem is still there but it is somewhere in the main style.css file. Something above the `.menu {...}` class causes the problem. Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Remove z-index: -1; from .menu. It didn't make any difference in the original code you posted, but here it does.
If then it still doesn't work: are you using the CSS or JS version of FontAwesome? If you're using the JS version use this selector: nav ul li:hover svg

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle for the CSS version: https://jsfiddle.net/TokerX/ny53m9fa/2/
And here's one for JS: https://jsfiddle.net/TokerX/ny53m9fa/3/